# proc.communicate not exiting on python subprocess timeout

Tags: python

The script below (a python process is called, which calls a waitfor cmd with a timeout of 4 seconds) is supposed to end after *4 seconds*.
But instead proc.communicate stops after the *20 seconds timeout*.

**Why???**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  proc_str = ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Anaconda3\\Python.exe",
                        "-c", "import 
  subprocess;subprocess.run('cmd /S /C waitfor g /t 200', shell=False, timeout=4)"]
  proc = subprocess.Popen(proc_str,
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            shell=False,
                            universal_newlines=True)
  (proc_out, proc_err) = proc.communicate(timeout=20)
  if (proc.returncode == 0):
     pass
```

**Everything works 100% ok if I remove the stdin/stderr/stdout parameters**

Comment: First run your code without exception handling and see what happens. Your script indeed ignores any exception that might occur while just one might tell you what's going on...

Comment: So in all you're running a python script, which runs a shell command with Popen to run some inline python code, which runs a shell command with subprocess.run(), right?

Comment: yes. It's the smallest example I could come up with that reproduces the issue. Obviously it not my production code; but except for the "cmd /S /C waitfor g /t 200", everything is pretty much what I use. I also need the stdin/out (not showed here)

Comment: Why are you running Python from Python to run a cmd command? That's at least one Python too many :)

Comment: So why do you have to resort to the command line to call the targeted Python code?

Comment: all: please do not try to solve a different problem here... the issue is that using stdin/stderr/stdout parameters to subprocess.Popen the process doesn't stop if the called process is a python getting a timeout...